# Hadoop: How to access a HDFS from an external IP?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, remote-access

Internally (i.e. internal network; private IP address-to-private IP address), I can access my HDFS just fine using:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://#.#.#.#/
```

However, when I try the same from a machine outside the network on which the HDFS namenode resides (obviously using the namenode machine's WAN IP instead of its LAN IP), I get:

```
ls: DestHost:destPort ec2-▒-▒-▒-▒.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020 , LocalHost:localPort mymachine/127.0.0.1:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

The namenode log reads:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 8020: readAndProcess from client ▒.▒.▒.▒:▒ threw exception [java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:3486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2600(Server.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:2144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:1389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:1216)
```

My `core-site.xml` reads:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Note that I have also tried setting the `fs.defaultFS` value to `hdfs://#.#.#.#:8020`.  I have also tried setting it to `hdfs://hadoophost:8020`, and adding `#.#.#.# hadoophost` to the top of `/etc/hosts`. (`#.#.#.#` is obviously the LAN IP of the namenode's machine in both cases.)  The results have been the same.

My `hdfs-site.xml` reads:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Note that I am able to `telnet` externally to the namenode's machine on port `8020` just fine.

What setting(s) am I missing to enable external access to my Hadoop file system?